# docker permission denied

Tags: docker

I tried to create a docker `htpasswd` by:

```
docker run --entrypoint htpasswd   registry:2 -Bbn dockerreg dockerreg > auth/htpasswd
```

but this turns out the following error:

```
bash: auth/htpasswd: Permission denied
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Is not quite clear what you are trying to do with the `docker run` command.

Your current command

```
docker run --entrypoint htpasswd   registry:2 -Bbn dockerreg dockerreg > auth/htpasswd
```

1. starts the docker container `registry:2`
2. ... with the entry point `htpasswd` command
3. the `htpasswd` command gets the options `-Bbn` and options `dockerreg dockerreg` (set password `dockerreg` for user `dockerreg`)
4. the output(!) of the `docker run` command is then forwarded to `auth/htpasswd`. This will create a `auth/htpasswd` file relative to the execution path of the `docker run` command. This is probably not intended and leads to the `Permission denied`.

I don't know, where the output of `auth/htpasswd` should be located, but you should specify an absolute path, e.g. `/home/myuser/web/auth/htpasswd` or some other folder where the user executing the `docker run` commands has access permissions.